# Remove repeated words in an item list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got a list with a number of items that contain some repeated text which I want to remove or hide. So from this:

```
<ul class="juicy">
<li>Juicy Green Apples</li>
<li>Juicy Green Tomatoes</li>
<li>Juicy Green Broccoli</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to achieve this:

```
<ul class="juicy">
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Tomatoes</li>
<li>Broccoli</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it always the same text? Or are you after a general solution for any duplicated words anywhere in the text?

Comment: Yes the words will be known before hand. And indeed there may be other strings too to remove.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.text()` method can handle this pretty easily if the text you are replacing is known beforehand.

```
var textToReplace = "Juicy Green",
    re = new RegExp(textToReplace,"i");
$(".juicy li").text(function(index,text){
  return text.replace(re,'');
});
```

Edit: answer to question in comment:

Something like this:

```
var textToReplaceArr = ["Juicy Green","Sour Yellow"];
for (var i = 0; i < textToReplaceArr.length; i++) {
  $(".juicy li").text(function(index,text){
    var re = new RegExp(textToReplaceArr[i],"i");
    return text.replace(re,'');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This works nicely. The words would indeed be known beforehand.

What if there were another set of words in the same UL that I wanted to remove? I've tried simply duplicating the code and replacing key words with another set, and that works. I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant / concise way?

Answer (score 0):

You want to try something dynamic?

```
$(document).ready(

function() {
    var repeatedWordsArray = new Array();
    var wordsToRemoveArray = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    $($("ul.juicy > li").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(" ").split(/\s+/g)).each(   //Joins the text of all elements, appends space between them and then splits with space character

    function() {
        repeatedWordsArray[this] = repeatedWordsArray[this] == undefined ? 1 : repeatedWordsArray[this] + 1;      //Increments the counter when the same word is encountered
        if (repeatedWordsArray[this] == 2) {     //If found twice, make a note of the word
            wordsToRemoveArray[i++] = this;
        }
    });
    if (wordsToRemoveArray.length > 0) {
        $("ul.juicy > li").each(
        function() {
            var ulElement = this;
            $(wordsToRemoveArray).each(
                function() {
                    var regexp = new RegExp('^\\s*\\w+\\s*$');
                    if(!$(ulElement).text().match(regexp)) {     //Do not match if the text of element contains a single word with or without spaces at its ends
                        regexp = new RegExp('\\s*' + this + '\\s*','g');
                        $(ulElement).text($(ulElement).text().replace(regexp, ''));   //Set the text of the element after removing the repeatedly found word
                    }
                }
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
);
```

This works for the following ul too:

```
<ul class="juicy">
    <li>Juicy Green Apples</li>
    <li>Juicy Green Tomatoes</li>
    <li>Juicy Green Broccoli</li>
    <li>Juicy</li>
    <li>      Green  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: James, that's pretty awesome. Thanks fot the suggestion. However, if I were to use the code, where would I insert the keywords that I want to remove?

Comment: You would not need to add a keyword to implement this. You would just need to specify the class name for those ul items for which this operation should take place. Here $("ul.juicy > li") determines for which items this should apply. 'ul.juicy > li' means that those immediate 'li' items inside 'ul' parent element who has the class with name 'juicy'. This happens twice in the code. If you replace this with your jQuery selector, everything should work fine.

Comment: Ah, I see. It just works automagically, squashing any recurring keywords in the ul. Thanks. Very neat.